How to define explicitly the Kasparov product $ x \otimes_B y \in KK_{i+j}^G (A,C) $ of $x \in KK_i^G (A,B)$ and, $y \in KK_j^G (B,C)$?
Let $A,B,C$ be separable $G-C^*$ - algebras. Then there is a biadditive pairing for $i,j \in \mathbb{Z}_2$,
$$ KK_i^G (A,B) \times KK_j^G (B,C) \to KK_{i+j}^G (A,C) $$
If $x \in KK_i^G (A,B)$ and, $y \in KK_j^G (B,C)$, can you explain to me in details how to define explicitly $x \otimes_B y \in KK_{i+j}^G (A,C)$ ?
Can you tell me as well when should we use $A,B,C$ to be graded, and when should we use $A,B,C$ to be ungraded in the case of the Kasparov product ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

The basics should be sketched out in Chapter VIII of Blackadar's $K$-theory for $C^\ast$-algebras? That said, there's been a lot of progress towards giving a much more explicit, geometric interpretation of this product in unbounded $KK$-theory; see, for instance, these lecture notes.

Thank you very much.  :-) Can you tell me please when should we use $A,B,C$ to be graded, and when should we use $A,B,C$ to be ungraded in the case of the Kasparov product ?

When you see just $KK(A,B)$, without a subscript, you can assume that the relevant $C^\ast$-algebras are $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-graded. If there's a subscript and it's always either $0$ or $1$, then you're likely to be working with ungraded $C^\ast$-algebras, but this isn't always the case---works in $KK$-theory are always careful to be precise about this. The relation between the two conventions comes from something called formal Bott periodicity. Again, this is all in Blackadar.

Thank you very much Sir.  :-)
